# I can't add nodes in node editor

Tags: node-editor

[image]
the add options are greyed out (in all tabs) I can't use them. Any help?
BLENDER VERSION: 2.78

Answer (score 7):

Check *Use Nodes* at the bottom of the **Node Editor**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable *Use Nodes* as Scott said if you want to add material nodes.
2. Switch to Compositor nodes which would have a separate *Use Nodes* button by clicking the second item in the enum.
3. You probably want to switch to Cycles at the top to have the "normal" nodes :-)

[image]